# LaTex math to ASCIImath conversion

Tags: javascript, mathjax, transpiler, asciimath

I have a javascript web application, and want to convert between strings of LaTeX math and strings of [ASCIImath](http://asciimath.org/). It seems that [MathJax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/api/index.html) could be able to do that, but I'm not to sure, what would be the best way.

Would it be easier to write a transpiler of my own (I don't know much about parsing, etc..)? Does anyone know if a library exists for this?

Comment: Asciimath is much less expressive than TeX-like input languages so going from LaTeX to asciimath will not be possible in general.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I would like it to work in the cases that it can work.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Mathjax supports the processing of ASCII math, and includes a few [preprocessing options](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/asciimath2jax.html).

Although you shouldn't need to convert between the two file types, if you look at the [ASCIIMath GitHub repo](https://github.com/asciimath/asciimathml), you'll see that they have two files:

- [ASCIIMathML.js](https://github.com/asciimath/asciimathml/blob/master/ASCIIMathML.js) - JavaScript functions to convert ASCII math notation
  and (some) LaTeX to Presentation MathML.
- [LaTeXMathML.js](https://github.com/asciimath/asciimathml/blob/master/LaTeXMathML.js) - JavaScript functions to convert (most simple) LaTeX
  math notation to Presentation MathML.

Comment: Yeah, I can convert from LaTeX to MathML, but how do I convert from MathML to ASCII math then?

Comment: See https://github.com/learningobjectsinc/mathml-to-asciimath, but take note of [this issue](https://github.com/asciimath/asciimathml/issues/8).

Comment: yes I just found that, and it works, thanks! Curiously, my web app (among the things it does) basically does what this guy needs, it parses html into (a subset of) LaTeX. But it does it for KaTeX, not for MathJax